# Exception ArrayOutOfBound while running Junit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a Junit for the below mentioned method

Can somebody suggest appropriate solution to this

After running the Junit i am getting below exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -84
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isBase64(Base64.java:137)
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isArrayByteBase64(Base64.java:163)
```

My test class

```
public class DecodeToObjectTest extends TestCase {


    public void testDecode() {
        try {
            String data="data";
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

                oos.writeObject(data);       
            // convert String into InputStream
             DecodeToObject.decode(new String(baos.toByteArray()));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The method which i need to test

```
public static
    Object decode(
            String input ) throws IOException,
                                  ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Log log = LogFactory.getFactory().getInstance(
                        "com.avocent.cps.report.service" );

        try
        {
            boolean c = Base64.isArrayByteBase64( input.getBytes() );

          if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            log.debug( "DecodeToObject :Entering Helper  Input: " + input );          }

            byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64( input.getBytes() );

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                                        new ByteArrayInputStream( data ) );

          if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            log.debug( "DecodeToObject :Object Input stream ois: " + ois );          }

            Object obj = null;

            obj = ois.readObject();


          if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
            log.debug(
                "DecodeToObject :Convering object to String: "
                + obj.toString() );
          }
            ois.close();

              if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
                        log.debug(
               "DecodeToObject :Decoded byte array to object successfully " );
               }

            return obj;
        }
        catch( ClassNotFoundException cnfe )
        {
                if(log.isErrorEnabled()){

            log.error( "DecodeToObject : Error :" );

                    }

            throw cnfe;
        }
        catch( IOException ioe )
        {

          if(log.isErrorEnabled()){
            log.error( "DecodeToObject : Error :" ); 

          }

            throw ioe;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I tried byte[] temp=new byte[10];
     /*ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

          oos.writeObject(data1);  */ 
   // convert String into InputStream
          
          byte[] s = Base64.encodeBase64(temp);
           DecodeToObject.decode(new String(s));

Answer (score 0):

It seems the input isn't `Base64` encoded. Try this :

```
boolean c = Base64.isArrayByteBase64( input.getBytes() );
if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
   log.debug( "DecodeToObject :Entering Helper  Input: " + input );          }

if(c) {
   byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64( input.getBytes() );
    // your code
}
```

But I suppose the `isArrayByteBase64()` is throwing the exception . Look at the [source code](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.java.htm) of

```
 private static boolean isBase64(byte octect) {
     if (octect == PAD) {
        return true;
    } else if (base64Alphabet[octect] == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
     }
 }
```

The static byte array `base64Alphabet` doesn't have element at index '-84' and hence `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Now I tried something like   byte[] temp=new byte[10];
     /*ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

          oos.writeObject(data1);  */ 
   // convert String into InputStream
          
          byte[] s = Base64.encodeBase64(temp);
           DecodeToObject.decode(new String(s));      It is now giving erro as        java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same Exception. The JUnit tests passed on my IDE, but failed on Maven build.

Switching from

> @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

to

> @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

fixed the issue.